# my json file does not load in angular js?

Tags: json, angularjs, routes

i have a basic project in angular js, with this files

index.html

```
 <div class="portfolio" ng-controller="portfolio-controller">
                <h3>Latest Works</h3>
                            <div class="col-md-6" ng-repeat="prt in portlist">
                                <div class="box-portfolio">
                                        <div class="ps">
                                            <div class="lp"><a href="#/{{ prt.id }}"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="box-descrip">
                                                <h4>{{prt.title}}</h4>
                                                <p>{{ prt.id }}</p>
                                                <p>{{prt.descrip}}</p>
                                        </div>
                                    <div class="back-sw"></div>                                       
                                    <img ng-src="images/misc/{{prt.img}}" alt="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                     </div>
```

controler.js --

```
var AppStart = angular.module('apps', ['ngRoute'])
AppStart.controller('portfolio-controller', function ($scope, $http){
          $http.get('app/portfolio.json').success(function(data) {
            $scope.portlist = data; 
          });
        });
```

portfolio.json --

```
[
        {
            id: "project_1", 
            title: "project1",
            img: "work1.jpg", 
            descrip: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam earu"
         },
        { 
            id: "project_2", 
            title: "project2", 
            img: "work2.jpg", 
            descrip: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam earu" 
        },
        {
             id: "project_3", 
             title: "project3", 
             img: "work3.jpg", 
             descrip: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam earu" 
         },
        {
             id: "project_4", 
             title: "project4", 
             img: "work4.jpg", 
             descrip: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam earu" 
         },
        { 
            id: "project_5", 
            title: "project5", 
            img: "work5.jpg", 
            descrip: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam earu" 
        },
        { 
            id: "project_6", 
            title: "project6", 
            img: "work6.jpg", 
            descrip: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam earu" 
        }
```

]

the issue is than angular does not load the json file in the index.html,
but with this code in controller.js work fine

optional code

```
     AppStart.controller( 'portfolio-controller', ['$scope', function($scope){

   $scope.portlist = [
        { id: "project_1", title: "project1", img: "work1.jpg", descrip: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam earu" },
        { id: "project_2", title: "project2", img: "work2.jpg", descrip: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam earu" },
        { id: "project_3", title: "project3", img: "work3.jpg", descrip: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam earu" },
        { id: "project_4", title: "project4", img: "work4.jpg", descrip: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam earu" },
        { id: "project_5", title: "project5", img: "work5.jpg", descrip: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam earu" },
        { id: "project_6", title: "project6", img: "work6.jpg", descrip: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam earu" }

    ]

}] )
```

i don't know what happened, i use yeoman and gruntjs

Comment: Looks like you have a typo? `$http.get('app/ortfolio.json')` should this be **portfolio.json** ?

Comment: use an error handler to help determine problems..... and look at path that request is made to in network tab of browser console

Answer (score 0):

You have misspelled the name of the file in your $http call:

```
$http.get('app/ortfolio.json').success(function(data) {
```

should be:

```
$http.get('app/portfolio.json').success(function(data) {
```

If that was just a typo in your question, please amend your question and provide the output of any console log messages/errors, and also confirm that you see the request being made in your Network tab in Chrome/Firefox/etc.

Comment: It was my mistake BUT STILL does not load the file with array

Comment: As requested above, please provide insight into what you see in your console and network logs. Is the request being made? Is the expected response being received?

Also, just pointing this out, but the Angular standard is proper-casing for controller names, as in PortfolioController. Angular has very particular rules about translating between Javascript casing and HTML words-with-dashes. Whether it is the problem or not, you should change this to follow the standard.

Comment: I changed the name of the controller but still does not show me anything in the view,

Comment: I changed the name of the controller, and the name folder where is the json, but still does not show me anything in the view, however,in the element inspector the file is loaded, http://juan.redcrear.com/test.jpg

Comment: Put `console.log(data);` in your success() handler to verify that it is getting fired and that `data` contains what you expect. It is very common to find that you actually want something like `data.data`, or that some unexpected issue is throwing an error even though the response looked correct.

Comment: ok I solved the problem, was very easy, as I could not see,the json file have a error, is [ {"id" : "project"} ]  not [ { id : "project"} ], I put no quotes :S thanks anyway!